# Collisions in ArcRotateCamera

Tags: 3d, webgl, babylonjs

I'm working on a 3D web project and I used Babylon.js. Currently, I'm studying the engine, doing and applying features I need one at a time. In this particular case, I've a simple ground with a box on top of it. I need to use ArcRotateCamera while having collisions enabled but the collisions aren't working as I am still able to pass through the box and the ground. Here is the code I'm working with on playground, its just modified from Babylon's collision sample: http://www.babylonjs-playground.com/#4HUQQ#14

I've already read Babylon's documentation with no luck, what could I be doing wrong here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed it for you:
http://www.babylonjs-playground.com/#4HUQQ#15

Basically the camera was initialized with a radius=0 and the collision radius was a zero-length vector